# ADF dataflow todate function

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, to-date

i m trying to convert the string todate() in format 'mm-dd-yyyy' [i.e., 01-21-2022] in ADF dataflow.
it looks it could not be done. it always converts to yyyy-mm-dd..
Is there anyway, i could able to convert into this format 'mm-dd-yyyy'

Answer (score 0):

Low mm is minutes. Use upper case MM for months.

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Date to String format**

```
toString(toDate('01-21-2022'), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```